# How can mark a word document as final "Mark as final" when using a Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I would like to mark my word document as final, i.e. it will be indicated as such when the document is opened and editing is restricted until the final mark is removed.

I know how this works using Word on a Windows computer 
[(see here)](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/prevent-changes-to-a-final-version-of-a-document-37281a8d-3c15-41f3-9a75-e6463acdf04f). However, I am using Word on a Mac OS X (Word version 15.33) and cannot find the function there.

Is it possible that the "mark as final" function is not available in the Word version for Mac?

Please note that I am not looking for the "Protect document" function [(see here)](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Password-protect-a-document-3E2D1A5E-2452-4546-B28E-06974FA21BEC), which I am aware of and works fine in the Mac version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function seems not to be available on the Mac version of Office Word.

(I asked the question as well in the [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/how-can-mark-a-word-document-as-final-mark-as/d8d1a572-6738-4679-99fa-16602fcff625))